# Need all rows from query, but only the 1st row for a specific column

Tags: sql-server

I am running a query on a table that returns multiple rows that I want to use SUM on so that I just get 1 row returned.  I can do that, and get the correct results using the following code:

```
SELECT E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.EmployeeNum,
  E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.JobNum,
  E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.OprSeq,
  SUM(E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.LaborHrs * E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.LaborRate) AS TotalLabor,
  SUM(E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.BurdenHrs * E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.BurdenRate) AS BurdenCost
FROM E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl
  LEFT OUTER JOIN E10Production.Erp.JobOper ON E10Production.Erp.JobOper.Company = E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.Company
    AND E10Production.Erp.JobOper.OprSeq = E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.OprSeq 
    AND E10Production.Erp.JobOper.JobNum = E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.JobNum
  LEFT OUTER JOIN E10Production.Erp.JobMtl ON E10Production.Erp.JobMtl.RelatedOperation = E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.OprSeq 
    AND E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.Company = E10Production.Erp.JobMtl.Company
    AND E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.JobNum = E10Production.Erp.JobMtl.JobNum
WHERE E10Production.Erp.JobOper.JobNum = '623165' 
  AND E10Production.Erp.JobOper.OprSeq = '20'
  AND E10Production.Erp.JobMtl.MtlSeq = '20'
GROUP BY E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.EmployeeNum,
  E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.JobNum,
  E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.OprSeq
```

The raw data looks like this:

```
EmployeeNum    JobNum    OprSeq    TotalLabor    BurdenCost
007349         623165    20        41.34         29.64
007349         623165    20        76.85         55.10
```

Once everything is GROUPed and SUM'd, it looks like this:

```
EmployeeNum    JobNum    OprSeq    TotalLabor    BurdenCost
007349         623165    20        118.19        84.74
```

The EmployeeNum, JobNum, and OprSeq are the same, TotalLabor and BurdenCost get SUM'd, it drops down to 1 line and it is exactly what I want.

Now I want to add one more column to the result

> E10Production.Erp.JobMtl.TotalCost AS MaterialCost.

So I added the column in the SELECT and GROUP BY in the query which now looks like this:

```
SELECT E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.EmployeeNum,
  E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.JobNum,
  E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.OprSeq,
  Sum(E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.LaborHrs * E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.LaborRate) AS TotalLabor,
  Sum(E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.BurdenHrs * E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.BurdenRate) AS BurdenCost,
  E10Production.Erp.JobMtl.TotalCost AS MaterialCost
FROM E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl
  LEFT OUTER JOIN E10Production.Erp.JobOper ON E10Production.Erp.JobOper.Company = E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.Company
    AND E10Production.Erp.JobOper.OprSeq = E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.OprSeq
    AND E10Production.Erp.JobOper.JobNum = E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.JobNum
  LEFT OUTER JOIN E10Production.Erp.JobMtl ON E10Production.Erp.JobMtl.RelatedOperation = E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.OprSeq
    AND E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.Company = E10Production.Erp.JobMtl.Company
    AND E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.JobNum = E10Production.Erp.JobMtl.JobNum
WHERE E10Production.Erp.JobOper.JobNum = '623165' 
  AND E10Production.Erp.JobOper.OprSeq = '20'
  AND E10Production.Erp.JobMtl.MtlSeq = '20'
GROUP BY E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.EmployeeNum,
  E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.JobNum,
  E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.OprSeq,
  E10Production.Erp.JobMtl.TotalCost,
  E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.LaborHrs * E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.LaborRate,
  E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.BurdenHrs * E10Production.Erp.LaborDtl.BurdenRate,
  MaterialCost
```

Just like EmployeeNum, JobNum, and OprSeq are the same, the TotalCost is the same as well, so I was hoping to see something like this:

```
EmployeeNum    JobNum    OprSeq    TotalLabor    BurdenCost    MaterialCost
007349         623165    20        118.19        84.74         101.26
```

But instead, I am getting this as my result:

```
EmployeeNum    JobNum    OprSeq    TotalLabor    BurdenCost    MaterialCost
007349         623165    20        41.34         29.64         101.26
007349         623165    20        76.85         55.10         101.26
```

For the life of me, I can not figure out why this is happening.  I don't know if it is an improper JOIN somewhere (I will admit, JOIN's still throw me for a loop), or if perhaps this is just a limitation of SQL and it can't do what I am asking.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Is there some keywords I can look up that can help me out with this?

Comment: You're grouping and aggragating on the same expressions. Don't put the things your aggragating on in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: GROUP BY E10Production.Erp.JobMtl.TotalCost not MaterialCost

Comment: Also you have left outer joins against `JobOper` and `JobMtl`, but then you add where clauses, which make those inner joins (since a where clause can only evaluate either (a) rows where those columns have data or (b) that those columns don't have data, using `IS NULL`). Remove `MaterialCost` from the `GROUP BY` (that won't even parse unless there's a `MaterialCost` somewhere that you haven't told us about). Consider aliases, too - doesn't typing `E10Production.erp.Labordtl.` 16 times become annoying? It makes it harder to read, too.

Comment: @Zeina I tried using both MaterialCost and E10Production.Erp.JobMtl.TotalCost with the same results.

Comment: @AaronBertrand That is what did it!  I took out the grouping on the 2 SUM fields, and it returned exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!